# How can I put a value into multiple % formats from formatString in Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to try this like what I can do in Python

```
stringValue = "Calculate: {0}+{0}={1}, {1}+{1}={2}".format(1, 2, 4)
(It may result "Calculate: 1+1=2, 2+2=4" in Python)
```

but I can't find anything that allows me to do that, except for the traditional formatting one using "%d" and multiple augments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that at `Utilities.formatString`, `n$` cannot be used. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) By this, `Utilities.formatString("Calculate: %1$d+%1$d=%2$d, %2$d+%2$d=%3$d", 1, 2, 4)` cannot be used.

So, as the workarounds, for example, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the template literal is used.

```js
const obj = {key1: 1, key2: 2, key3: 4};
const stringValue = `Calculate: ${obj.key1}+${obj.key1}=${obj.key2}, ${obj.key2}+${obj.key2}=${obj.key3}`;
console.log(stringValue)
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `replace` is used.

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 4];
const stringValue = "Calculate: {0}+{0}={1}, {1}+{1}={2}".replace(/{([0-9]+)}/g, (m, p) => ar[p]);
console.log(stringValue)
```

#### References:

- [formatString(template, args)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)